# What is the fastest way to insert and move a rectangle object into a linear octree?

Tags: octree

So I have build a linear (basically an array) octree containing rectangular objects (like bounding boxes). Every node has an unique index, all child indexes (if present) and parent node index (if not root). I split every node that intersects one of the rectangles until depth limit is reached and those become leaf nodes.

After that I want to insert new rectangular objects and move existing ones in this octree. Rebuilding octree from 0 seems like a very inefficient way and that is what I am currently doing. There should be a faster strategy, especially taking into account that all objects are rectangular.